# Why don't volts and amps necessarily increase together in Watts = Volts*Amps? Don't more volts = more amps and vice versa?

Tags: physics, circuits

I'm trying to understand modern American housing circuitry, which have 15 and 20 amp breakers and work on 120v circuits. They're described using the simple formula Watts = Volts*Amps.

I'm using physics logic I've read online to understand this.

I understand volts as electrons in a high state of energy ready to move to a lower state of energy (because they constantly repel each other) and the higher the voltage the faster they travel through a circuit once released (120v vs 240v for example).

I understand amperes as the amount of a fixed quantity of electricity (electrons), called a coulomb, that can travel through a circuit in a second, so

1 amp = 1 coulomb/sec

Just from these definitions, **I don't understand how more amps don't automatically increase voltage given that voltage is the actual force that is pushing the coulombs through the circuit? What allows more coulombs to travel through a circuit per second is literally the voltage isn't it? Therefore, as one increases, the other should also increase.** However, this is not the case, and it makes housing circuits confusing for me.

For example, with 15 and 20 amp American housing circuits:

120v*15amps = 1800 watts and 120v*20amps = 2400 watts

**How exactly can amps increase (amount of coloumbs traveling through circuit per second) without increasing the voltage and how can voltage increase without inadvertently increasing the amps?**

Btw, I'm assuming higher voltage with even lower amps than 120v*15amps is also possible. I'm also assuming that somehow resistance and AC vs DC is related to this somehow.

I apologize if this is a dumb question, but I'm genuinely confused.

Edit:

I'm not confusing the total amount of energy from a housing circuit with energy required for a specific load. I was using the differences in the max loads of 15 and 20 amp circuits to describe how amps can be different with a fixed voltage. I shouldn't have said "breaker," and I should have used a more specific example.

The meat of my question is really how amps can be different for a load with a fixed voltage, i.e an iPhone vs a toaster connected to 120v circuit have different amps. How can amps increase or decrease without also increasing or decreasing the voltage? Voltage dictate the speed the coulombs are moving aka amps. They seem to literally mean the same thing or are directly proportional somehow. How can more or less energy (different amps) be traveling through a 120v circuit if the 120v's traveling is intrinsically that energy?

Another way to say this, what does it mean in a physical sense for 15amps to travel through a circuit vs 20 amps to travel through a circuit?

Comment: Because you don’t have a fixed load. Google “voltage stiff”. Your voltage is kept at a fixed value at all times.

Comment: Because resistances can be changed too.

Comment: Because real loads can be non-linear, meaning that the increase in current is not proportional to the increase in voltage, or vice-versa.

Comment: Spellbinder, Are you more interested in a closer-to-reality explanation or would a simple (but totally unrelated) analogy be your goal? We can go either way with this. If you want to stay with electrons, then you will need to gather up a few ideas since electrons aren't marbles. They are more like a gas cloud (Drude model approximation.) And they are motivated to move by static charges stuck to the surfaces of things. There are no hands-on equivalents. So you have to think a little more closely. (How do electrons know which branch to take as they arrive at a Y in a circuit??)

Comment: "iPhone vs a toaster connected to 120v circuit have different amps" -> look up Ohms law.  You'll probably be able to answer this question yourself.

Comment: Hmm I've always found it rather intuitive to think of electrons as a fluid travelling through an assortment of structures.  Voltage analogous to pressure.  It's intuitive that with the same pressure difference, a pipe twice the size has twice the flow.  Similar to with a gas, higher pressure can be obtained by either increasing particle density or by increasing energy level of the particles.  To look at two conductors of the same size but different material, you can think of one as a smaller pipe, or a pipe full of mesh or some obstruction.  Only good for understanding flow really though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make a distinction between two different things that you are blurring together. First, there is a rating for a circuit. 120V at 20 Amps. That is how much it can deliver if it is connected to the right load. 2400 Watts is the maximum capacity of the circuit. Then there is the details of real loads. How do they work and how will they behave if you change something? It is best to be a bit more specific even when considering hypotheticals.

Let's say you measure the voltage at a home in north america, it will be approximately 120V. But it might be 124V. That is perfectly normal. Let's say we hook up an old-fashioned light bulb to our 124V house power. Now we can measure the current, too. Let's say it is 0.5A. So our lamp is consuming about 60.2 Watts. So this is an operating point. 124V and 0.5A which gives us 60.2 Watts.

If we could INCREASE the VOLTAGE, then the current and power would increase, too. So you are right that they increase together. But the way household circuitry is designed is that the voltage is held constant. The mains power from the utility company is supplied to your house as a FIXED voltage. We don't get to change it, and the utility company does not let it change by much either.

So you can't increase the voltage, really. There is no knob to turn it up with.

Likewise, you don't have a way to increase the load current (in this scenario). When you connect a fixed load to fixed household voltage, the load decides how much current it will take at the voltage which is offered. It doesn't matter whether the capacity of the circuit is 1800 watts or 2400 watts. Our load only needs 60.2 Watts and that is all it will take.

But you could add another lamp in parallel and get more current that way. Maybe some variable loads (like a fan with low, medium and high setting) can be adjusted. But anyway, in all cases, the utility company holds voltage fixed, and the load takes the current it needs to do its job.

After reading  your edit, I guess I would add one more thing. Voltage and current are not the same. Voltage tells you how bad the electrons (or other charges) want to move. Current tells you how many electrons (or other charges) are actually moving past a given point each second. For some loads, such as heating elements, by their nature they will always enforce Ohm's law (V = I * R). The designer of a heating element can make the resistance higher by making the element longer or skinnier, or choosing a different material.

Smart loads may use transistors to vary the current. Transistors are capable of switching really fast or just kind of acting like a variable resistor so they can create a choke point that limits current flow as needed. The electrons may REALLY want to move (high voltage) but the transistor meters the flow, only allowing a certain number per second to flow. So this is one reason why loads can vary.

Ultimately, the utility company PRESENTS a voltage. Dumb loads enforce Ohm's law. Smart loads use transistors to control the current flow. The power consumed is voltage * current.

I hope this makes things more clear to you.

Comment: What you said here kind of alludes to what I'm confused with:

"Likewise, you don't have a way to increase the load current (in this scenario). When you connect a fixed load to fixed household voltage, the load decides how much current it will take at the voltage which is offered. It doesn't matter whether the capacity of the circuit is 1800 watts or 2400 watts. Our load only needs 60.2 Watts and that is all it will take."

However, I've edited my question further to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

Your standard mains sockets always have AC voltage of 120V, within some tolerance.  A single breaker can provide multiple wall sockets, so a 10A breaker allows powering a single 10A load (e.g. 1200W heater) on single socket, or up to ten loads of 1A each (e.g. 120W lamps). If you only turn on 1 lamp, only 1A flows, so different loads exist. So all loads use same voltage but they draw as much current as they need. If the load is something like a computer requiring 100W all the time, it will take more or less current depending on the voltage if it fluctuates within tolerance during the day.

Comment: Yeah, but I think the OP is trying to "think physically" about "countable things" like electrons. He thinks that an increased current must entail an increased voltage to achieve it. The idea of a load is probably a bit of a struggle when thinking about electrons as marbles and some at "high energy" and others at "low energy."

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the total amount of energy ((available)) before protection (circuit breaker/fuse) kicks in, and the energy required by any one particular load device.  With a little high-school algebra, you can see that any one of these equations can be created by substitutions in the other equations.

Ohm's Law:  E = I x R

Watt's Law:  P = E^2 / R

Joule's Law:  P = I^2 x R

Other:  P = I x R

These all describe the Voltage/Current/Power relationships in a thing; Resistor (like a hotplate), Inductor (like a motor), etc.

My house has 200 amp electric service.  That is, at 240 Vac, the most I can suck out of the transformer on the pole is 200 A.  But everything in my house draws less current.  For example, a 60 W light bulb draws 0.5 A at 120 V.

Another way to see it is that electric power distribution is a constant voltage, variable current system.  The voltage is held constant at 120/240/whatever volts, and devices draw whatever current they need *at that voltage*.

The realities are much more complex (pun intended), involving phase angles, imaginary power, power factor, etc.  But for a basic understanding, if you stick with resistive loads, AC power in a home is similar to DC power in a flashlight.

Comment: You have posted your reply twice. Please delete one.

Comment: I've edited my question for further clarification. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine voltage is like water at the top of a mountain. It wants to flow downhill, and if it has the opportunity to do so, but how it will. This desire of the water to flow is like voltage, it's potential. It doesn’t represent movement, it is static. But the path it takes and size of its channel it takes could either work against or with the flow of water downhill. So it's path (current or amps) could decrease or increase.